# Integrate adyen payment gateway with Paypal and iDeal

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, paypal, payment-gateway

I want to integrate Adyen payment gateway in my app and can accept the payment form PayPal and iDeal. How can I integrate it with iOS native app ?

I looked their document and github example but didn't find any way for it.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

For PayPal and iDEAL, we do not have a direct API for these methods, but they can be accessed through the Hosted Payment Page integration. However, rather than redirecting to the HPP, you can use our Directory Lookup functionality (section 2.3.3 of our [HPP Manual](https://www.adyen.com/dam/jcr:d00b49c2-1ad9-4617-a6ed-0013ce7670ce/HPP%20API%20Manual.pdf)), which is recommended especially for iDEAL, or simply just display the logos and pass in the brandCode in as part of the POST request, sending it to https://[test/live].adyen.com/hpp/details.shtml.

For support, the easiest thing to do is email our support team at support@adyen.com.

Hope that helps! Best of luck!

Paul